# how i can open different stage in one windows in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

**Dears Developers I have more stages but when I open any stage is showing as the following picture in down so please dear developers I need it in one window just how I can code it ?**

---

[image]

this code for example for open stage

```
@FXML
    public void btnsaveinvoice() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FX/saveinvoice.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("saveInvoice");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/restlogo.png")));
        stage.show();

    }
```

and this is for the salesinvoice open stage

```
@FXML
    public void opensalesinvoice() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/FX/salesinterface.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/restlogo.png")));
            stage.setTitle("SalesInvoice");
            stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create new Window.", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking how to have your entire application use just one Taskbar button in Windows? Or do you want all your stages to open within the same parent window?

Comment: Yes Mr Zephyr i need it in one taskbar button

Answer (score -1):

You need to set parent stage for the child stage like so

```
childStage.initOwner(parentStage);
```

EX.

```
@FXML
public void btnsaveinvoice() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FX/saveinvoice.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("saveInvoice");
    stage.iniOwner(primaryStage); // or whatever your primaryStage is
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/restlogo.png")));
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: check my edited code and replace the primarystage with your own

Comment: Thanks dear ahmed  (primaryStage) you mean to call  the function from another class

Comment: PrimaryStage is the stage that opens the save invoice stage
accept the answer so maybe someone else can use it